# go: How to differentiate between empty strings and nil in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a MongoDB document containing the `name` attribute, which can be an empty string. Currently, I have the following code to differentiate when a user sends a value (including an empty string) or simply does not send any value:

```golang
func(s *Store) NamespaceUpdate(ctx context.Context, id string, name *string) {
    changes := bson.M{}
    
    if name != nil { // nil when the user does not want to update it
        changes["name"] = name
    }
    
    // more attributes here

    _, err := s.db.Collection("namespace").UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": id}, bson.M{"$set": changes})

    return err
}
```

However, as more attributes are added, the function signature and the number of if statements will increase. To solve this, I added a `NamespaceChanges` structure and passed it to the function:

```golang
type NamespaceChanges struct {
    Name *string `bson:"name,omitempty"`
}

func(s *Store) NamespaceUpdate(ctx context.Context, id string, changes *NamespaceChanges) {
    _, err := s.db.Collection("namespace").UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": id}, bson.M{"$set": changes})

    return err
}
```

The main challenge lies in distinguishing between empty strings and nil, as the `omitempty` tag will omit both empty and nil values. Is there an "`omitnil`" or a similar option available?

Comment: simply use a string type. not a pointer. then you can update whenever a field is given a non-empty string. if given value is empty string simply do not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are under the assumption that an empty string ("") in a `*string` is omitted. That is the key to solving the problem however.

If you have a `*string` field, only `nil` is omitted, a pointer to an empty string is not omitted. That is how you can differentiate between the 2 cases.

See also [How to update Mongodb fields with omitempty flag in Golang structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158987/how-to-update-mongodb-fields-with-omitempty-flag-in-golang-structure).

Note: on a `string` field, an empty string is omitted, because it is the zero value for `string`. For a pointer type the zero value is `nil`, so only a `nil` is omitted. It is always about the zero value of a type. Here is a full [list of zero values in Go](https://exercism.org/tracks/go/concepts/zero-values).